# How to customize legends in livecharts in winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, livecharts

How to customize legends in livecharts in winforms ? I was trying to get some thing like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfPbH.png).

In live chart winforms, I can only see these two options

```
scatterChart.LegendLocation = LegendLocation.Right;
scatterChart.DefaultLegend.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

But this wont help me to achieve a legend as I shown in the link. Would like to know some solutions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a DefaultLegend and add our properties into it and assign to chart's DefaultLegend as follows :

```
DefaultLegend customLegend = new DefaultLegend();
customLegend.BulletSize = 15;
customLegend.Foreground = Brushes.White;
customLegend.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;

cartesianChart1.DefaultLegend = customLegend;
```

Answer (score 0):

This perfectly works .Thanks

```
DefaultLegend customLegend = new DefaultLegend();
customLegend.BulletSize = 15;
customLegend.Foreground = Brushes.White;
customLegend.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;
 customLegend.FontSize = 9;
cartesianChart1.DefaultLegend = customLegend;
```