# LiveCharts change color for legend names C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, livecharts

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeYiJ.png)

This is my graph showing everything right except "Legend" area. I have used this code to set up where legend will be.
`cartesianChart1.LegendLocation = LegendLocation.Bottom;`

Also every time I add new value I added title for each value and it works as intended as you can see:
[Values work but not on legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwwM7.png)

How do I change color of each value in legend? (You can see better when you zoom in picture its black)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53499556/how-to-customize-legends-in-livecharts-in-winforms) topic I managed to do it

```
DefaultLegend customLegend = new DefaultLegend();
customLegend.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
cartesianChart1.DefaultLegend = customLegend;
cartesianChart1.LegendLocation = LegendLocation.Bottom;
```